# Command to generate c = "a + b" in console, when 1000's of value "a" and "b" added in MySQL manually

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have three columns in my database:

`a` = value
`b` = value
`c` = a + b

User usually enters `a` and `b` in the form, and the value is stored in the database. `c` will be calculated by the model.

In my model:

```
class Calculate < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_validation_on_create :update_c
  before_validation_on_update :update_c

  def update_c
    if !a.blank? && !b.blank?
      self.c = a + b
    end
  end
end
```

Just a sample code above. So `c` is generated everytime the user clicks "Save".

Now, I am an admin, and I populated 1000's of values for `a` and `b` using phpMyAdmin CSV import:

```
id=1, a=4, b=7, c=
id=2, a=1, b=6, c=
id=3, a=3, b=2, c=
.
.
.
```

Milliondollar question:

**What is the best way to do it in console or somewhere else, to tell Rails to generate C for all the 1000's of entries?**

Thank you!

UPDATE 1:

Actually the `c = a + b` is not that simple in my code. Take `geocode_address` as `c`, `address_geo` as `a, b`, here is the full code:

```
def geocode_address
if !address_geo.blank?
  geo=Geokit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(address_geo)
  errors.add(:address, "Could not Geocode address") if !geo.success
  self.lat, self.lng = geo.lat,geo.lng if geo.success
end
```

end

Comment: Not sure why you want to do this.  It seems that if "c" can be derived from a & b, then in general, you shouldn't have a "c" column in your database (unnecessary duplication).  I imagine that it's better to derive c "on the fly".

Answer (score 1):

I would just connect to MySQL directly (or run the SQL through phpMyAdmin) to issue an update statement.

I'm assuming you want to update ALL the records.

```
UPDATE table SET c = a + b;
```

That'll do it for you, nice and fast. I'm guessing you know what the table name is, I'm not familiar with Rails. I don't think you need Rails for this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Calculate.update_all("c = a+b")
```